# How to check an image already existed in database in which objects are from two different SQL tables?

Tags: html, sql-server, asp-classic

I am doing this project (classic asp and SQL) in which I have an input box from which image name is taken after clicking "Update" button. Once the update button is clicked, available/pre-existing images shows up or displayed in a table.  Before storing this image name, I have to check whether this image is already in database or not.If there is already an image, I should give an error message saying "This image already existed in database". The problem I am having is, i don't understand how do I check two objects in different forms. In other words, my input box is in a form in which it execute one SQL table and the record-set that get displayed in the table cell is from another table of database.

```
    <% 
            Response.Write "<form name=updateinfo action=images.asp?id="& Request.QueryString("ID") &" method='post'>"
            Response.Write "<input type=hidden name=update value=actionaddimage>"
            Response.Write "<input type=hidden name=id value="& Request.QueryString("id")&">"
         %>  
    <tr> 
        <td align="center" bgcolor=#E0EAFD colspan=2>
            <input type="text" name="image" value="<%=objRS("image")%>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPDATE"><br /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
<!--div for displaying images-->                
<div> 
    <table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=0 width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="text-align:left">
                <% 
                    DIM Sql1, Rs1,Cnt1
                        Cnt1=1
                    Sql1 ="SELECT TOP (10) np.imgId, p.name, p.productID, p.pack1, p.brand, p.image, np.imgName,np.imgThumbName, np.imageTitle, p.discontinue_YN, pf.flavor FROM product p "&_
                               "INNER JOIN NewProductImage np "&_
                               "ON np.productId = p.productID "&_
                               "LEFT OUTER JOIN product_flavors pf "&_
                               "ON p.flavor = pf.id "&_
                               "WHERE np.productID='"&request.QueryString("id")&"' "&_
                               "ORDER BY productID"
                    SET Rs1 = objConn.Execute(Sql1)

                    IF NOT Rs1.EOF=true THEN 
                    %>  
                    <% 
                        IF objRS("image") = Rs1("imgName") THEN
                            Response.Write "<div id= 'errormsg'>**This image is already in database.</div>"
                            Response.Write "<br />"
                        END IF  
                        %>  
                        <span>More Views:</span>
                    <% END IF %>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <%
                    IF NOT Rs1.EOF=true THEN 
                    %>
                    <center>
                    <%
                        Response.Write "<table><tr><td>Image Big</td><td>Image Small</td></tr>"
                         WHILE NOT Rs1.EOF
                        %>
                        <%
                            'Response.Write "<td class='tdcell'>"& Rs1("productID") &"</td>"
                            Response.Write "<tr><td><a href='abc.asp?id=" & Rs1("productID") & "'><img src='http://www.example.com/images/products/1400/"& Rs1("imgName") &"'></a></td>"
                            Response.Write "<td><a href='abc.asp?id=" & Rs1("productID") & "'><img src='http://www.example.com/images/products/250/"& Rs1("imgName") &"'></a></td>"
                            Response.Write "</tr>"
                            %>
                        <%
                            Rs1.moveNext
                        WEND
                            Response.Write "</table><br />"
                            %>
                    </center>
                    <%
                    END IF  
                        Rs1.close
                        SET Rs1= nothing
                    %>
                </div>  
</div>
```

So, the value for input box i.e value="<%=objRS("image")%>", it is from a product table and it is inside a form. And another table is newProductImage to display the images in the table. I tried to do "JOIN" and did checking as shown above:

```
IF objRS("image") = Rs1("imgName") THEN
                        Response.Write "<div id= 'errormsg'>**This image is already in database.</div>"
                        Response.Write "<br />"
                    END IF
```

But the logic doesn't work. I also tried doing

```
IF Rs1("p.image") = Rs1("np.imgName") THEN
                    Response.Write "<div id= 'errormsg'>**This image is already in CDN.</div>"
                    Response.Write "<br />"
                END IF
```

it gives me an error "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal". Can you please help me out how do I check?

Comment: This: `"WHERE np.productID='"&request.QueryString("id")&"' "&_` is a very very **VERY** bad thing to do. It makes it trivial to hack the page to do anything I want to your database.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Just regarding Joel's comment, check out the rest of the site for using [stored procedures and parameterisation](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp-classic%5D+stored+procedures+parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I would have made a comment but not enough coin.

Try writing it with NOT EXISTS or EXISTS instead of your JOIN. 
I had to rewrite some code the other day that looked similar to what you are doing. I ended up going with WHERE NOT EXISTS but also with WHERE EXISTS

Here is my resource link [MSDN Exists (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)

This will give you another code option.

Updated 1-13-2016 3:30PM CST

The plan here is to discover if PRODUCT P.IMAGE matches NEWPRODUCTIMAGE NP.IMGNAME.

If we have a match..

```
IF RS.EOF=False Then
```

or how you wrote it

```
IF NOT RS.EOF=True THEN
```

We can then skip the additional match which isn't going to work correctly if I recall. 
The WHERE EXISTS does this check for you.

```
If objRS("image") = RS("ImgName")
```

If you need to call the image you know it's there because it's not a False return.

str = RS("image")

```
Sql ="SELECT product.name, product.productID, product.brand, product.image "&_
     " FROM product "&_
         " WHERE EXISTS "&_
         "("&_
         " SELECT 1 "&_
         " FROM NewProductImage "&_
         " WHERE LOWER(NewProductImage.imgName) = LOWER(product.image) "&_
         " AND LOWER(NewProductImage.imgName) = "&LCase(str)&" "&_
         ")"&_
     " AND product.name Is Not NULL "

        SET RS = objConn.Execute(Sql)   

        If RS.EOF=False THEN 

                Response.Write "<div>This image is already in db.</div>" 
        End If

        Set RS = Nothing
```

WHERE LOWER(imgName) = LOWER(image) gathers up matching images.
AND LOWER(imgName) = "&LCase(str)&" tells us the image you are testing or looking in both tables for.

In the example using the "&str&" you should only need it on one place.

I added one AND statement so you can see a bit more of the formatting. 
Updated to match lower case.

Comment: Can I still do join with EXISTS or no? because I still need to display information of both tables under an image which i didn't show in details in above code.

Comment: From the MSDN Link Examples D and E show you can use a JOIN. You should setup a test to see if the results are what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried new sql: Sql ="SELECT  p.name, p.productID, p.brand, p.image FROM product p "&_
            "WHERE  EXISTS "&_
            "(SELECT imgName from NewProductImage AS np "&_
             "WHERE np.imgName = p.image)"
   SET Rs = objConn.Execute(Sql)          
             
   IF NOT Rs.EOF=true THEN  
    IF objRS("image") = Rs("imgName") THEN
      Response.Write "<div>This image is already in db.</div>" but it gives me error "Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." I am not sure if I could do IF objRS("image") = Rss("imgName")

Comment: @LouManizer i've updated the answer to show you a bit more on how the WHERE EXISTS functions. We do not need to check again if the images match because the SQL statement did that for us, on top of that we aren't looking to call from the other table. I'm not sure if you need to return from Rs imgName or just the objRS which is what I posted.

Comment: When I implemented SQL as you suggested, its gave me that message all the time (meaning although the image name doesn't match). I think the logic is not working. If both images are of same name, then only it should be giving that message. I am not quite sure yet that what am I missing

Comment: I wonder if your images are named like Image1.JPG in that case it would not match image1.jpg would have to LOWER(np.imgName) = LOWER(p.image) to get a match if case is the issue.

Comment: That message appears even when the page loads so I was wondering if the logic is checking the image names or not.

Comment: What I wrote is just going to match anything in the two tables. 
If I wanted to check to see if I have an image in any table I need the input. Otherwise, this is triggered at the first match. Add " AND p.name = 'image.jpg' " to the end, try it with a known image in one table, then one in both and one that's not present in either.

Comment: I updated the code, assign a value to str and test it.

Comment: @LouManizer while you build your query (If you haven't finished it) remove your Table Aliases. The logical order and processing many not be suited for the EXISTS format.